# how to optimize two ajax call in single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have two ajax call in my script. one is working other is not. but both are working individual. they are not nested and there is no dependicy on each other. 
only first ajax call is working second one is not. 
my script is:

```
    $('textarea').mentiony_user({ //@
        onDataRequest: function (mode, keyword, onDataRequestCompleteCallback) {
          $.ajax({
                url: "search_user_list.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {keyword: keyword},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                   var data = response;
                   // console.log(data);
                    data = jQuery.grep(data, function( item ) {
                        return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                    });
                    onDataRequestCompleteCallback.call(this, data);
                    // setTimeout(data, 1000); 
                }
            });
        },
timeOut: 500, // Timeout to show mention after press @
    });

    // item list

    $('textarea').mentiony_item({ //#
        onDataRequest: function (mode, keyword, onDataRequestCompleteCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search_item_list.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {keyword: keyword},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
               var data = response;
               console.log(data);
                data = jQuery.grep(data, function( item ) {
                    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                });
                onDataRequestCompleteCallback.call(this, data);
                // setTimeout(data, 1000); 
            }
        });
    },
timeOut: 500, // Timeout to show mention after press @
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What you mean by not working? What to do you mean by optimize?

Comment: what is mentiony_user and mentiony_item in this context?

Comment: @acdcjunior both are working individual. both are not working together. when i run my script only first one is working .

Comment: @AnthonyL  mentiony_user and mentiony_item is my method name.

Comment: Can you add the methods to the question, otherwise it is difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Anthony its a lots of code. its plugin how can i add these code here!

Comment: Can you post a plunker or fiddle that shows your issue? It is difficult to analyse without more code.

Comment: @NiK648 i added a plunker , you can find all the code here : https://plnkr.co/edit/SDrIKmOXGyOepRNxRQnf?p=preview